# Can not deploy Windows 8.1 app in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

A few days ago I stopped being able to run new Windows 8.1 apps I created in Visual Studio 2013. It is failing when it tries to register the app for deployment. It seemed to happen after I converted an old 8 product to 8.1 however all new 8.1 apps create now have this problem. This is what I receive when I try to deploy.

Error    1   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. Deployment Register operation on Package a7b2c016-e1b6-48f6-bdb4-0b75ae15e1e4_1.0.0.0_neutral__w7mxzscebfmq4 from:  (c:\users\joe\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\BlankApp2\BlankApp2\bin\Debug\AppX\AppxManifest.xml)  failed with error 0x80080005. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235160 for help diagnosing app deployment issues. (0x80073cf9) BlankApp2

I did make sure my windows developer license was current.

It doesn't seem to match other registration errors I have seen in my searching.

Update: It appears to have had something to do with a windows update I had done the day before. Using a system restore point to revert to got it working again. The error code 0x80080005 appears to be a COM error in relating to the registry or communicating with different windows services. I couldn't find anything though in relating it to registering of Windows 8.1 apps however. Any further insights people may have would be appreciated.

Comment: I am also new to windows 8 development but clean the solution and delete the bin folder close the visual studio then reopen and try to build it again may resolve this solution some time.

Comment: I did try that and it doesn't make a difference. The build itself is always fine. It is when it actually goes to register it that it seem to have the problem.